# Anonymize Form Inputs on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm trying to anonymize all form inputs and only save 1 or 0 for data entered, or not. Why? The form is part of a psychological study in which the only thing of interest is whether the respondent has entered any content at all.

I have set `onsubmit = "anonymize()"` and I have tried following code:

```
function anonymize() {

   var formFields = ["name", "age", "location"];
   formFields.forEach(loop);

   function loop(field) {
     if (field.value.length > 0) {
      document.getElementsByName(field).value = 1;
     }
 }
}
```

The form id/name is "name", "age", "location". I tried "get by ID" and "get by Name". I have set the same name and id per form input field.

Anyone has a idea what I could do to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over an array of strings, not form fields.

```
   var formFields = ["name", "age", "location"];
   formFields.forEach(loop);

   function loop(field) {
     console.log(field) // "name"
     console.log(typeof field) // "string"
     console.log(field.value) // undefined

     if (field.value.length > 0) { // Error can't read length of undefined
      document.getElementsByName(field).value = 1;
     }
   }
```

So `field.value.length` should give you an error since `field.value` is undefined and field is just a string.

Here is a solution using [form.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) that don't require you to search for DOM elements

```js
$form.onsubmit = function anonymize (evt) {
   const { elements } = evt.target
   ;["name", "age", "location"].forEach(name => {
     elements[name].value = elements[name].value.length ? 1 : ''
   })
}
```

```html
<form id="$form" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="POST">
  <input name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input name="age" placeholder="Age">
  <input name="location" placeholder="Location">
  <input name="Favorite food" placeholder="Favorite food">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The params field in function loop is a string, so the statement "field.value.length" doesn't make sense